# Connecting To Multiple MySQL Databases in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to have some type of dropdown that shows a list of all the databases from the specified host. Basically, my goal is for user to be able to select one of the databases from the dropdown and be able run a report. But I am stuck on how I can connect to the host and be able to display the list into the dropdown. I have done some research, but I am not getting any clear answer of how to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`SHOW DATABASES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html) Just connect without the `database` parameter, then run a query for the above command.

Comment: @ChrisG - Thank you so much for you input. Makes total sense. Mind if I ask you a follow up question? I got that to work, but what will be the best way of doing a multiple queries? Part of my plan was to "SHOW" databases, then "USE" the database, run SELECT queries etc. Also, for some reason I can't seem to understand on how to go in and out of different databases.

Comment: You need to put the code you've tried in the question and describe how it fails. The main thing you need to achieve is to build an express server that runs arbitrary queries in sequence based on incoming requests. I can't really tutor you here obviously; suffice to say that I've successfully run a `USE` query and a subsequent `SHOW TABLES` query, without issue.

Comment: If you're using node-mysql, you'll probably want to have it change the connection for you. Since often different databases also have different usernames and passwords, this is all covered in one call. Look at: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#switching-users-and-altering-connection-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get database name, query `information_schema.TABLES` database.

```
SELECT Table_schema AS 'Databases' 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema`;
```

Then do your report query for example like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`tablename` WHERE date >= 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND date <= 'XXXX-XX-XX';
```

Where `dbname` is the database name that you pass from the dropdown list to the backend query.